# Таблицы в базе данных MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Вообщем, хочу создать что-то вроде дневника.

***Проблема вот в чем:***

Планирую создать таблицу `user`, где будет информация о пользователе (`id, login, password, email`);

***Теперь вопрос о второй таблице.***

При создании записи, пользователь должен будет выбрать предмет (математика, физика или другое), который будет закреплен к этому пользователю. Тоесть, я хочу создать вторую таблицу с `id` пользователя, по которому я буду узнавать какие предметы мне нужны.. И в этой второй таблице создать колонки с названиями полями - предметами. А позже связать их.

*Но, допустим, если я хочу, чтобы было больше 15 уроков. Это же глупо делать 15 разных колонок.* **Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как мне с этим бороться.**

---

*Кстате, если мне например в колонку с названием `"Предметы"` в таблице `'users'` сделать типом `SET` и тогда название предметов отделять запятой.*

Comment: Создайте 3 таблицы в бд. В одной будут user, в другой предметы, в третей стыковка id user'а и id предмета.

Comment: @Egor, можете рассказать подробней о третей таблице? Что-то не понял, как я должен узнавать `id` предмета. Я должен создавать `id` для предметов в второй таблице?

Comment: Да, конечно. Сейчас приложу фото-пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По моему это называется 3 нормальна форма в реляционных баз данных.

```
table users
id   login  password  email
1    aaa    bbb       test@test.com
2    xxx    yyy       xyz@xyz.com

table subjects
id   name  price
1    A     25
2    B     30
3    C     50
```

Связываете их через 3 таблицу.

```
table users_subjets
user_id  subject_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        3
```

Comment: Вот, да. То, что я и хотел написать

Comment: @Egor Пока вы хотели я уже писал,и оценил вас в комментариях :)

Comment: Ну а если мне `users -> id` надо несколько предметов?

Comment: Ну так и пишите один id пользователя, но разные предметы в 3-ей таблице

Comment: Я так понял, здесь нету ключевых полей?

Comment: Рекомендую `user_id` и `subject_id` в `table users_subjets` связать между собой. Это нужно для того, чтобы, если вы пытаетесь удалить предмет из второй таблиц, но он используется в третей, то систем вам просто не позволит это сделать.

Comment: @Cactus 3 таблица лишь связывает.Там и пишите какой пользователь какой предмет

Comment: @Egor По моему это зависит от поставленной задачи.Пусть оформляет как следующий вопрос будем определяться

Comment: Как мне в третей таблице `user_id` дать несколько предметов, что бы я потом мог оперировать этим значением..

Comment: @Cactus если поля `user_id, subject_id`  ссылаются на соответствующие поля через `foreign key` то должны иметь те типы на курьих они ссылаются

Comment: Угу, ясно. Спасибо:)

Comment: @Cactus "Как мне в третей таблице user_id дать несколько предметов," `user_id 1, subject_id 1,  user_id 1, subject_id 2, user_id 1, subject_id 3`

Comment: @Cactus пожалуйста